# Why Does all Linux apps (Firefox etc) not self update like Telegram?

Tags: updates, firefox, telegram

i wonder why the apps in linux ubuntu does not self update like Telegram desktop app in linux which updates itself.

Comment: Software Installs using snaps do update.

Comment: @MartinThornton I don't think this is a duplicate. The question is about 'why', not 'how to'.

Answer (score 1):

Traditionally, all GNU/Linux distros ship their own packages. The developers release the source code of a new version, and the package maintainers package them, and and the updates are distributed through the official channels (all packages are digitally signed by the maintainers, and the package manager will refuse to install the update if the package has been tampered by an attacker).
Telegram is available from Ubuntu's official repositories too, but that package is [only updated](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software) when one upgrades to the next release of Ubuntu.

If you install Telegram from a [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eatareao/+archive/ubuntu/telegram), or a [snap](https://snapcraft.io/telegram-desktop)/[flatpak](https://www.flathub.org/apps/details/org.telegram.desktop), it won't self update, and you can update it like other apps, as per your convenience.